# Kernel lauch specifying the stream, but with default shared memory size

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I need to specify the stream for a kernel launch in CUDA. The kernel uses some shared memory with its size defined in the kernel code.

```
static const int cBlockSize = 256;

__global__ fooKernel(void* param)
{
    __shared__ uint32_t words[cBlockSize/16];
    // implementation follows, using 2 bits of shared memory per thread
}
```

However, the shared memory size parameter goes before the stream parameter in a kernel launch expression. So how to tell CUDA to use shared memory size specified by the kernel code and ignore what's in the launch code?

```
fooKernel<<<N/cBlockSize, cBlockSize, /* What to put here? */, stream>>>(param);
```

Obviously, I would like to avoid code duplication putting `(cBlockSize/16)*sizeof(uint32_t)` there again. In reality the expression is more complex.

Comment: @tera , I can't remove `__shared__` because that memory is indeed shared between threads in a block.

Comment: you do understand that the kernel launch shared memory argument is the *dynamically* allocated size? if you have no dynamically allocated shared memory, just use zero

Comment: Sorry, my my comment was nonsense because my brain tried to fill in the missing bits to make it a dynamical allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statically allocated and dynamically allocated shared memory are treated separately, in many respects.

If you have no intention of using dynamically allocated shared memory, it is safe to pass [the default value](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration) of zero as the third kernel launch parameter, regardless of any intentions you may have around the use of statically allocated shared memory.

Comment: To be clear, there is no default value when a stream parameter is specified.  If you intend 0 in that case, you must explicitly pass zero.  The only time the default parameter is in effect is if the last 2 kernel launch parameters are not specified.